# Passing input from one shell to another shell, and returning the input back again

Tags: linux, bash

So, I'm looking for a way to pass input from one shell to another. I'm working on a program that spends a lot of time sending commands to the OS for it to execute, using the default shell (in my case, bash). I need the changes made to the shell (changes in the local directory, new aliases, stuff like that) to "stick", and I was hoping to do that by keeping a hidden but persistent bash process around to do the bidding of my program. Is there a good way to go about this?

I'm essentially writing a program that runs on top of bash, processing input that it understands and passing input that it doesn't understand on to the OS to execute. The problem is, when I go to change the active directory, it will change the active directory in a throwaway shell; it will open an sh process, change the directory of it, and then close that process before I have a chance to do anything with it. I want to keep an sh or a bash process around and reuse it, interactively, to do what I want it to. This said, I don't want that process visible to the user from the desktop environment.

This being said, I have not been able to find a way to get this to work, and I'm not sure where to go from here.

Ideas, anyone? I'm already using rlwrap, but that isn't fixing this problem because it was never meant to.

Comment: It's not very clear what you are asking, but did you consider using [screen](http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen) ?

Comment: You're correct, its not very clear. I apologize. Edits made.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    shopt -s expand_aliases
    source ~/.bash_aliases
    set -o allexport
    youraliashere
```

This should make aliases and local directories stick when you run your shell, unless you were looking to run it interactively, I may have misunderstood your question.